# NixOS の nix-env が Killed とだけ表示されて終了してしまう

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

### 経緯

標準の `nixos` box on Vagrant on VirtualBox に Ruby 処理系をインストールしようとしています。以下の `Vagrantfile` があるディレクトリで作業しています。

```ruby
# Vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "nixos/nixos-18.03-x86_64"
end
```

`vagrant up` のあと `vagrant ssh` で NixOS 上のシェルに接続しました。
そのあと nixpkgs から `nix-env -i ruby` で Ruby をインストールしようとしたのですが、出力の最後に `Killed` と出て中断されてしまいます。終了ステータスは `137` であり、異常終了でした。以下はそのログです。

```sh
$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Fri Jun  8 13:38:06 2018 from 10.0.2.2

[vagrant@nixbox:~]$ ruby
ruby: command not found

[vagrant@nixbox:~]$ nix-env -i ruby
installing 'ruby-2.5.0'
these paths will be fetched (3.61 MiB download, 17.82 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/j9l2p2c1yhgb227cbr9n4yrd3x2h92gp-ruby-2.5.0
copying path '/nix/store/j9l2p2c1yhgb227cbr9n4yrd3x2h92gp-ruby-2.5.0' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
Killed

[vagrant@nixbox:~]$ echo $?
137

[vagrant@nixbox:~]$ ruby
ruby: command not found
```

NixOS に詳しくないため環境全体としておかしいのかもと思って試しに `nix-env -i wget` としてみたのですが、こちらは正常終了し、`wget` がインストールされました。

### 質問

- どうすれば正常に Ruby をインストールできるのでしょうか？
- なぜ `nix-env -i ruby` が中断されてしまうのでしょうか？

  - どこかにログが残っているでしたら知りたいです。簡単に探した程度では見つかりませんでした。

### 環境

- ホスト: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic, VirtualBox 5.2.12 r122591 (Qt5.9.5), Vagrant 2.1.1
- Vagrant box: `nixos/nixos-18.03-x86_64`
- Vagrant box 内の NixOS の情報:

  ```sh
  [vagrant@nixbox:~]$ nixos-version
  18.03.131807.489a14add9a (Impala)

  [vagrant@nixbox:~]$ nix-env --version
  nix-env (Nix) 2.0
  ```

### 追記: メモリについて

コメントでのご指摘を受け、メモリ不足かどうか確認するために2つの端末で `vagrant ssh` し、片方で `nix-env -i ruby`、他方で `while sleep 1; do free -h; done` をしてみました。すると最初は下のような値だったものが、

```
[vagrant@nixbox:~]$ while sleep 1; do free -h; done
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           993M         39M        914M        3.4M         39M        862M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

だんだんと free が減っていき、最終的に下の値で止まりました。

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           993M        904M         63M        3.4M         25M        4.4M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

`Killed` が表示されて `nix-env` が終了すると元の値に戻ったため、確かに Vagrant/VirtualBox 内のメモリを使い果たしているようです。

Comment: [nix-env uses a ton of memory](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/38635) たぶんメモリが足りていないです。 インストール作業中に別端末から `top` や `while sleep 1; do free -h; done` のようなコマンドで観察してみて下さい。

Comment: @mjy さん、コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘の実験を行い、結果を追記しました。特にメモリを使いすぎているようには見えなかったのですが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: @mjy さん、確かにそうですね、すいません。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。試してみたところ、どうも確かにメモリ不足のようです。ゲスト側のメモリ上限を増やして再挑戦してみます。

Comment: @mjy さん、[こちらの回答の方法](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26468913/5989200)を使って Vagrant 側のメモリ上限を 1024M から 2048M に引き上げ `vagrant reload` してから再び ssh して `nix-env -i ruby` したところ、インストールが正常に終了しました。適切なご助言ありがとうございます！　よろしければ回答として投稿して頂けませんか？（ご面倒であれば自己回答の形にします。）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### メモリー不足による終了

`nix-env` は素直に使うとメモリーの消費量がとても多いようです。
参照: [nix-env uses a ton of memory](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/38635)

システムの残メモリーが危機的に少なくなった際には、プロセスが目的を達成する前に終了してしまうことがあります。
終了する理由は2通り考えられます。

- OOM Killer に強制終了される
- リソースの要求（メモリーの確保やプロセスの起動など）をOSに断わられ、プロセス自身が続行不可能と判断して終了する

質問のケースは `Killed` としか表示されていないので、おそらくOOM Killerによるものです。
OOM Killerに強制終了された場合は、プロセス自身はログを残せません。
システム側のログに残ると思います。
例えば `systemd` を使用しているシステムであれば、

```
journalctl |grep -iE 'oom|kill'
```

のようにして強制終了のログを検索します。

#### `nix-env` のメモリー消費を抑える方法

現在では、`--attr（-A）` オプションを使い、引数には単純なパッケージ名でなく "attribute path" を指定するのが一般的なようです。

```
sudo nix-env -iA nixos.ruby
```

この場合の `nixos.ruby`("attribute path") は、

```
nix-env -qaP ruby
```

で見つかりますが、この検索もメモリー不足で終了するかも知れません。
そういった場合は、[NixOSのパッケージ検索ページ](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html)で調べることもできます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。`nixos.ruby` を使う方法ですと、Vagrant デフォルトのメモリ上限のまま、上限を変更せずともインストールが成功しました。